# Xamarin: multiple request network pop ups in android 10, when try to connect to wifi in IOT module

Tags: xamarin, iot, esp8266, android-wifi

I am working on an IOT module with wifi connection,I am testing using a samsung with android 10.
The chip is a ESP8266.The Wi-Fi signal, does not have an internet connection.
the project is developed in xamarin.

The problem, is when I try to connect to the device's signal. When I'm making the connection request, multiple pop ups appear in the device, requesting the connection, and it does not wait until it is connected, immediately the device launches the connection requests again and again, finally crash.

when i'm debugging, the NetworkAvailable runs, but even the phone does not finish connecting to the signal, the phone lunch a new request network again, don't wait until you are actually connected, and I don't know why multiple requests are launched.

Here is my code.

```
 public async Task<bool> Connect(string WiFiName, string WifiPassword)
        {
            bool result = false;
            var formattedSsid = $"\"{WiFiName}\"";
            var formattedPassword = $"\"{WifiPassword}\"";
    
            try
            {
               
                    AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    
                    var wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .SetSsid(WiFiName)
                    .SetWpa2Passphrase(WifiPassword)
                    .Build();
    
                    var networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi) // we want WiFi
                    .SetNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier) // we want _our_ network
                    .Build();
    
                    UnregisterNetworkCallback(_networkCallback);
    
                    _networkCallback = new NetworkCallback()
                    {
                        NetworkAvailable = network =>
                        {
                            result = true;
                            autoResetEvent.Set(); //signal
                        },
                        NetworkUnavailable = () =>
                        {
                            result = false;
                            autoResetEvent.Set(); //signal
                        },
                    };
    
                    connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(networkRequest, _networkCallback);
    
                    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    
               
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
               
            }
            finally
            {
            }
    
            return result;
        }
    
        private void UnregisterNetworkCallback(NetworkCallback _networkCallback)
        {
            if (_networkCallback != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _connectivityManager.UnregisterNetworkCallback(_networkCallback);
    
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                } finally
                {
                    _networkCallback = null;
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    public class NetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    {
        public Action<Network> NetworkAvailable { get; set; }
        public Action NetworkUnavailable { get; set; }
    
        public NetworkCallback()
        {
         
        }
    
        public override void OnAvailable(Network network)
        {
            try
            {
                WiFiAndroid.connectivityManager.BindProcessToNetwork(null);
                WiFiAndroid.connectivityManager.BindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex;
            }
        }
    
        public override void OnUnavailable()
        {
            base.OnUnavailable();
            NetworkUnavailable?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

[image]

the image, is the request that is throw over and over again.